# Drool run twice with globals and without facts?

Tags: drools

```
global java.util.List rules;
global java.util.Map ruleParamsMap;
global java.util.List invoiceRowIds;

  function BigDecimal sum(List invoiceRowIdsValue, String docType) {
     return RuleHelper.sum(invoiceRowIdsValue, docType);
 }

rule "example"
when    
    Boolean(booleanValue == true) from rules contains "TestedValue"
    $amount : Integer() from ruleParamsMap.get("amount")
    $sum : BigDecimal() from sum(invoiceRowIds, "IV")
    Boolean(booleanValue == true) from $sum.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf($amount)) <= 0
then
    System.out.println("RUN");
 end
```

Here is my rule and for some reason, it prints RUN twice.
Any ideas why?

Comment: How do you invoke the rules? Are there other rules which call `update`?

Comment: I invoke it once in java in one place. ruleExecutor.execute(ruleName, globals);

Comment: RulesEngineFactory.getStatelessRulesEngine(rule.getPath(), globals);

Comment: Are you sure this is drools? RulesEngineFactory is from openL. If this were drools I'd expect you do be doing `kieBase.newStatelessKieSession();`, then on the session calling `setGlobal` and `execute`....

Comment: Yes it is "drools.compiler.languagelevel" "1.6"

Comment: That's ... really not relevant. It just means you happen to have a drools property in your config files or possibly your runtime arguments. What is the dependency you're pulling in, including the version? Because there's no "RuleEngineFactory" in drools. You sure that's not some sort of local wrapper?

Comment: Yes, it is local wrapper for drools.

Comment: So how is _it_ firing the rules?